# Web reference Lists.asmx is not working on SharePoint 2010?

Tags: web-services

We have a windows service that pulls the data from SharePoint. It is working just fine on the SharePoint 2007 environment however throws the below error on SharePoint 2010. Is there a quick fix? else should I need to add the Lists.asmx as a service reference as recode completely?

```
elemList = (XmlElement)listWS.GetListItems(listName, null, query, view, "", null, "");

(XmlElement)listWS.GetListItems(listName, null, query, view, "", null, "")  Cannot call 'Lists.Lists.GetListItems(string, string, System.Xml.XmlNode, System.Xml.XmlNode, string, System.Xml.XmlNode, string)'
```

because it is a web method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have to re-create SharePoint Lists Web Service proxy and re-build solution in VS.

### References

[How to: Add a Reference to a Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)